# Jersey resource with multiple paths

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to migrate the way my resources are named, from Portuguese (and singular) to English (and plural), and I was wondering if Jersey currently supports multiple @Paths for the same resource, so I could make this transition painless to the users of my system.

From:

```
@Path("/usuario")
public class UsersResource {

    @POST
    public Response create(User user) {
        ...
    }
}
```

To:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UsersResource {

    @POST
    public Response create(User user) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Cheers!

Comment: I think that is supported meanwhile the path is not repeated in the application, or you will get a pretty nice resource exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to work with multiple paths:

```
@Path("/{parameter: path1|path2}")
```